# Vue.js tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap tooltip in my vue.js component. But no matter what I do it won't work.

I use this:

```
<a href="/url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="site">My site...</a>
```

**Vue:**

```
created {
     this.$nextTick(() => {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
     });
}
```

In my `app.js` I require bootstrap and jquery:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

How do I get this to work!!!!!

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle example with your code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure bootstrap-sass is just the styles, what do you get when you type `$().tooltip` in the console?

Comment: When I do that I receive:  ```function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.tooltip')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option
```